# Can numbers be hardcoded in an AGAL operation?

Tags: flash, syntax, low-level, stage3d, agal

If I try to simply add 1.0 to one color-channel of a register, can I:

- Write it directly with some float-number syntax I'm not aware of, or...
- Do I have to pass in the number to a constant first, and use that constant register there?

Example of what I'm trying to do:

```
//AGAL code - Just trying to add one to red-value of ft1, and assign it to ft2
add ft2.r, ft1.r, 1.0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately no, you have to pass the constant in. via fc0, etc

```
add ft2.r, ft1.r, fc0.r
```